# How to turn an array made by nltk.tree into another tree?

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, tree, nltk, spacy

I have a list made by [nltk.tree.Tree](https://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.html?highlight=tree#module-nltk.tree)

```
>>>question = 'When did Beyonce start becoming popular?'
>>>questionSpacy = spacy_nlp(question)
>>>print(questionSpacy)
[Tree('start_VB_ROOT', ['When_WRB_advmod', 'did_VBD_aux', 'Beyonce_NNP_nsubj', Tree('becoming_VBG_xcomp', ['popular_JJ_acomp']), '?_._punct'])]
```

The goal is to make another tree. I know it's stupid, but otherwise I do not know how to know if a tree representing a sentence is contained in another representing another sentence.

I made an attempt but it wasn't successful. I think I didn't take every case into account. Sometimes the parent node has to be  `array[0].label()` and sometimes `array[0]`.

```
from nltk import Tree

class WordTree:
    def __init__(self, array, parent = None):
        #print("son :",array[0][i])
        self.parent = []
        self.children = [] # if parenthesis then it has son after "," analyse : include all elements until the next parenthesi
        self.data = array
        #print(array[0])
        for son in array[0]:
            print(type(son),son)
            if type(son) is Tree:
                print("sub tree creation")
                self.children.append(son.label())
                print("son:",son)
                t = WordTree(son,son.label()) # should I verify if parent is empty ?
                print("end of sub tree creation")
            elif type(son) is str:
                print("son creation")
                self.children.append(son)
            else:
                print("issue?")
                break # prolbem ?
```

And when I run `t = WordTree(treeQuestion, treeQuestion[0].label())` I get the following output :

```
<class 'str'> When_WRB_advmod
son creation
<class 'str'> did_VBD_aux
son creation
<class 'str'> Beyonce_NNP_nsubj
son creation
<class 'nltk.tree.Tree'> (becoming_VBG_xcomp popular_JJ_acomp)
sub tree creation
son: (becoming_VBG_xcomp popular_JJ_acomp)
<class 'str'> p
son creation
<class 'str'> o
son creation
<class 'str'> p
son creation
<class 'str'> u
son creation
<class 'str'> l
son creation
<class 'str'> a
son creation
<class 'str'> r
son creation
<class 'str'> _
son creation
<class 'str'> J
son creation
<class 'str'> J
son creation
<class 'str'> _
son creation
<class 'str'> a
son creation
<class 'str'> c
son creation
<class 'str'> o
son creation
<class 'str'> m
son creation
<class 'str'> p
son creation
end of sub tree creation
<class 'str'> ?_._punct
son creation
```

As you can see, in `('becoming_VBG_xcomp', ['popular_JJ_acomp'])` it uses the letters of the son, `popular_JJ_acomp`, to make several sons rather than its name to make one son. This is an error of course. Therefore **how to turn an array made by nltk.tree into another tree ?**

Answer (score 0):

I think I have find something that transform an array made by nltk.tree to a tree made with Python it but I haven't been able to generalise it yet.

```
from anytree import Node, RenderTree

class WordTree:
    '''Tree for spaCy dependency parsing array'''
    def __init__(self, array, parent = None):
        """
        Construct a new 'WordTree' object.

        :param array: The array contening the dependency
        :param parent: The parent of the array if exists
        :return: returns nothing
        """
        self.parent = []
        self.children = []
        self.data = array

        for element in array[0]:
            print(type(element),element)
            # we check if we got a subtree
            if type(element) is Tree:
                print("sub tree creation")
                self.children.append(element.label())
                print("son:",element)
                t = WordTree([element],element.label())
                print("end of sub tree creation")
            # else if we have a string we create a son
            elif type(element) is str:
                print("son creation")
                self.children.append(element)
            # in other case we have a problem
            else:
                print("issue?")
                break
```

Indeed it works well with the following example :

```
[Tree('start_VB_ROOT', ['When_WRB_advmod', 'did_VBD_aux', 'Beyonce_NNP_nsubj', Tree('becoming_VBG_xcomp', ['popular_JJ_acomp']), '?_._punct'])]
```

Giving :

```
<class 'str'> When_WRB_advmod
son creation
<class 'str'> did_VBD_aux
son creation
<class 'str'> Beyonce_NNP_nsubj
son creation
<class 'nltk.tree.Tree'> (becoming_VBG_xcomp popular_JJ_acomp)
sub tree creation
son: (becoming_VBG_xcomp popular_JJ_acomp)
<class 'str'> popular_JJ_acomp
son creation
end of sub tree creation
<class 'str'> ?_._punct
son creation
```

But I have no outputs when trying:

```
for i,sent in enumerate(sentences):
    i = WordTree(sentences, sentences[0].label())
```